# Matlab error while creating a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to insert 'double' type values in a matrix. For that I am creating a matrix with following lines of Matlab code:

```
dpitchcnt=(N/256); %N is total number of byte
pitchvec(1:int64(dpitchcnt)); %creating a matrix 'pitchvec' with 1 row and int64(dpitchcnt)' columns   
size(pitchvec) %Trying to display the size.
```

I am getting the following error  while carrying out the above operation:

> Undefined function or method '_colonobj' for input arguments of type
>   'int64'. Error in ==> sample at 31 pitchevec(1:int64(dpitchcnt));

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `varName(1:10)` will get the first 10 values of `varName`, not create the variable `varName`;

To create a matrix you can use

```
pitchvec = zeros(1,int64(dpitchcnt)); %A zero-matrix
matrixSize = size(pitchvec);
```

You can also use `ones(n,m);%Create a n times m matrix with 1 all over.`